# Why does collection.find_one({ _id: id }) always return nothing even with correct string id?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I am working on a MongoDB-based API webserver to learn Rust and I can't figure out why I can't get results:

```rust
use mongodb::bson::{doc, oid::ObjectId};
use mongodb::{error::Error, Database};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct Job {
    _id: ObjectId,
    user_id: String,
    organisation: String,
    role: String,
}

async fn find_job_by_id(database: &Database, id: String) -> Result<Option<Job>, Error> {
    database
        .collection("jobs")
        .find_one(Some(doc! { "_id": id }), None)
        .await
}
```

I've tried printing out the `id` at every step and it always looks correct, but `.find_one()` always returns `Ok(None)`. Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried performing the same operation using the mongo cli? Provide the command  and result when you try it there.

Comment: I figured it out in the end. Turns out it can't execute filter options on ObjectIds using String types. You have to specifically turn the string from the request to an ObjectId then use it to filter it. Took me a while, but this seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out filters for `ObjectId` fields have to be specifically use `ObjectId`. You can't apply filters using strings as I was doing over there. This method is what fixed it:

```rust
let id = ObjectId::parse_str(id).unwrap();
```

Looks like the myths were true... rust is pretty harsh with type checking...

Comment: This is actually on MongoDB, not Rust; you’d get the same issue in the MongoDB shell (and if MongoDB had type checking, it would prevent the mistake).